# Corrected expired date

Tags: ios, swift, date

I try to detect user input of expired date with current date.
for current date, i use `let now = Date()`
for expired date after user input in textfield is:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_GB")
print("echo date input:\(self.textInput.text!)")
return dateFormatter.date(from: self.textInput.text!)! as Date
```

but after I compare expire date is count one day before inputed date:

```
echo date input:18/09/2020
```

and expired date function return is : `2020-09-17 17:00:00 +0000`
and current date is : `2020-09-18 08:42:11 +0000`
expired date function return not same like date input in textfield. How to correct this? If expired date < now it will return false.

update, after I change to GMT or UTC:

```
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")
```

or

```
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
```

return is `2020-09-18 00:00:00 +0000` which count as expired date < now (still incorrect). which actually expired date == now

Comment: Where are you now exactly? What's `TimeZone.current` returning?

Comment: @Larme, when I print TimeZone.current is Asia/Jakarta (current)

Comment: You should prepare both date objects with the same timezome and locale before any comparison as you will get this behaviour across different time zones. Best for comparison is to set the time zone to UTC and then run the comparison

Comment: And don't you have 7h difference from UTC? So `2020-09-17 17:00:00 +0000` is midnight at your place? See the issue? You are saying that "18/09/2020" will be midnight at YOUR timezone, so it returns `2020-09-17 17:00:00 +0000`. That's normal. But in fact, you wanted it to be midnight where? UTC? Always prefers UTC "comparison", and format the output for the user only, but use the same timezone always internally (UTC highly encouraged).

Comment: @Larme, in my current time is 2020-09-18 actually, not 2020-09-17 17:00:00 +0000

Comment: It's because you converted "18/09/2020" saying it's midnight 18/09/2020 according to your timezone, which is in fact in UTC `2020-09-17 17:00:00 +0000` the same date. That's what I meant.

Comment: Wait. " which actually expired date == now" but you have "2020-09-18 00:00:00 +0000" and "2020-09-18 08:42:11 +0000" how are they supposed to be equals? Date are not "day sensitive", there are also hours, minutes, etc. You want to test on the "same day"? Or `18/09/2020` means `"2020-09-18 23:59:59`?

Comment: @Larme, i want to test "same day" without hour and etc. I test GMT and UTC return same 2020-09-18 00:00:00 +0000

Comment: @Pancho, UTC and GMT return same 2020-09-18 00:00:00 +0000

Comment: @Sarimin that is true for the current day/light saving. In the winter when GMT changes the time with one hour you will start seeing a difference. This is why UTC is recommend as it never changes

Comment: Why don't you simply use a date picker and set the maximum date to today?

Comment: @LeoDabus, this is just to compare user input of expired date then compare with current date, if expired date until today it is still return true. user requirement not use date picker.